# Migrate Wordpress site to self hosted server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, wordpress, self-hosting

I have been ask to migrate Wordpress site from an online host like Godaddy to an self hosted server. By self hosted I mean that they have created their own host server. 
My problem is. How and where should I import the database? In Godaddy I would have option to login to phpmyAdmin to export or import database. But how about self hosted? Please let know how do I go on with this process.

Comment: You need to install LAMP stack in your hosted server, you can start with a personal test bed using MAMP https://www.mamp.info/en/. Not a programming question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After installing LAMP, will I need to create new database for my website and install Wordpress? I am sorry for many questions. I have never had self hosting server and do not know how it works ir practise. On online hosting, when I migrate the site, I would upload all files, create a new database for that site and then import that database. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If that's a self hosted server, you will need to know what did you use to run the server. For example, if that's XAMPP, there are one-click install functions for phpmyadmin, wordpress etc.

Take a look here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have not build this self hosted server. I only received FTP login and was asked to migrate Wordpress site to the self hosted site. I can upload the wordpress file, but I have no idea where to import database. So they will need to install some kind of phpmyadmin to the self hosted server? Do they also need some Wordpress tools?